# Pattern matching and NonCommutativeMultiply

Tags: pattern-matching, built-in-symbols

I am trying to define some functions using `NonCommutativeMultiply` and I am experiencing some strange behavior.

Consider the following expression

```
expr = Hold@MatchQ[f[a, g[b, c]], f[_, g[_]]]
```

Clearly the pattern should not match and indeed

```
ReleaseHold[expr]
(* False *)
```

However, substituting the function `g` with `NonCommutativeMultiply` gives

```
ReleaseHold[expr /. g -> NonCommutativeMultiply]
(* True *)
```

I was thinking that it might have to do with the attributes of NonCommutativeMultiply, but

```
SetAttributes[f, Attributes[NonCommutativeMultiply]]
ReleaseHold[expr]
(* False *)
```

Why does `NonCommutativeMultiply` match in this weird way?

Comment: `expr /. g -> Times` behaves the same "weird" way. I think it is because of the shared attributes `Flat` and/or `OneIdentity`: try `Intersection @@ (Attributes /@ {Times, NonCommutativeMultiply})`  and see [OneIdentity](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/OneIdentity.html) and [Flat](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Flat.html).

Comment: A few things: You need to set the attributes of `g`, not `f`. It is indeed a question of the attributes: For `Flat` functions, `f[_]` matches anything that matches `f[___]`, since both are equivalent to `f[f[___]]`. The strange thing is that in order for it to return `True`, you need to reevaluate the definition of `expr` - it looks like something about the attributes of `g` is stored in the internal representation of `expr` which prevents matching

Comment: @LukasLang Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: also: [OneIdentity >> Properties and Relations](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/OneIdentity.html) _**"When f is both Flat and OneIdentity, a and f[a] are identical for pattern matching: "**_  Thus  `NonCommutativeMultiply[a, b, c] /. 
 NonCommutativeMultiply[x_, y_] :> {x, y}` gives `{a, b ** c}`